# Check connection to mysql database using a timer

Tags: c#, mysql, timer

I need to check the connection at any time so to do that I thought about putting a timer
 and put the checking connection inside.
It works but I have a problem it blocks all the controls when I disconnect from the database.
Everything is blocked, textbox button etc.
Here is the code that I put in the timer:

```
string connetionString = null;
        MySqlConnection cnn;
        connetionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=user1;UID=root;PASSWORD=";
        cnn = new MySqlConnection(connetionString);


        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            base_off.Visible = false;
            base_on.Visible = true;
            base_on.Top = (this.Height - base_on.Height) - 9;
            base_on.Left = (this.Width - base_on.Width) - 10;
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            base_on.Visible = false;
            base_off.Visible = true;
            base_off.Top = (this.Height - base_off.Height) - 9;
            base_off.Left = (this.Width - base_off.Width) - 10;
            cnn.Close();
        }
```

Here base_off and base_on are status of the database.
 When base_off appears everything is blocked... 
Any help please ? 
Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to do `cnn.Close();` in the catch block as code only jumps to catch if it cannot open a connection. Hence you re trying to close a connection which is not open, i suppose. 
Or you can check if connection is open only then close it.

Comment: Are you getting any error or when you debug where does the debugger get stuck.

Comment: No I don't get any error but just that all my controls are blocked

Comment: Step through the above code and see where your app is blocked, does the debugger stop at cnn.close()?

Comment: Everything stop when I disconnect my WAMPServer and then the picture base_off appears

Comment: More I think about it, its not cnn.close thats causing the issue it might be some code that depends on WAMPServer

Comment: So there is not a solution ?